# how to provide more broker users in bosh-release-rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, cf-bosh

I would like to use CF release of rabbit-mq and provide more BOSH release/deployment defined broker users ( for sake of tracing issues)

Is there a way to provide so ?
Currently i'm using stock release
https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cf-rabbitmq-release
 and in deployment i declare single user ?

```
 properties:
  rabbitmq-server:
    plugins:
    - rabbitmq_management
    administrators:
      broker:
        username: foo      #user to read and send events
        password: bar
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can see by looking at the spec for the rabbitmq-server that only 2 accounts are identified as valid properties. `broker` and `management`

```
  rabbitmq-server.administrators.broker.username:
    description: "RabbitMQ admin username for broker"
  rabbitmq-server.administrators.broker.password:
    description: "RabbitMQ admin password for broker"
  rabbitmq-server.administrators.management.username:
    description: "RabbitMQ admin username for operator"
  rabbitmq-server.administrators.management.password:
    description: "RabbitMQ admin password for operator"
```

https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cf-rabbitmq-release/blob/623a0bfac64ec6820175d3589ba6233435bf912f/jobs/rabbitmq-server/spec#L37

If you know rabbit internals and want to cut your own bosh release you could modify the init-script and create additional administrator users for your use case. The script already uses the same function for operator and broker accounts, and looks like a straightforward pattern to follow. https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cf-rabbitmq-release/blob/623a0bfac64ec6820175d3589ba6233435bf912f/jobs/rabbitmq-server/templates/rabbitmq-server.init.bash#L77

But when you say "tracing issues" I wonder if the operator account is indeed what you're looking for. If so just add that to the job details.

```
 properties:
  rabbitmq-server:
    plugins:
    - rabbitmq_management
    administrators:
      broker:
        username: foo      
        password: bar
      management:         #operator account details
        username: foo     
        password: bar
```